# Got exception in the sharepoint wizard after install sp1 on sp2013 foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, update

I am using sp2013 foundation. I try update sp with this sp: `sharepointsp2013-kb2880551-fullfile-x64-en-us`

I installed the sp and finished. I did a reboot. After the reboot I start the wizard. I press a couple of times on next and the I saw a progress bar. After 2 seconds I got this error:

The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Locks', database 'SharePoint_Config'

This is the full error:

```
Task initialize has failed with an unknown exception 
06/26/2014 14:52:31  9  ERR                  Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'Locks', database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPLock.Acquire(SqlSession sqlsession, SPLockType type, String objectname, Guid& lockid, String& server, String& commandline, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.AcquireFarmUpgradeLock(Boolean bForce, Boolean singleClickInstall)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.InitializeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
ClientConnectionId:9f1f69eb-dc64-4ba7-9a5d-60daca7e5c21
06/26/2014 14:52:31  9  INF                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
06/26/2014 14:52:31  9  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
```

What is this, I logged in with farm account.

Comment: can you make sure the account having the DBO permission on the Config DB, if already just reset it(remove and re add). also if possible more details about the psconfig log(attach it)

Comment: I'd go through the permissions for that account in SQL, like @WaqasSarwarMCSE mentioned. Is there any other non-SharePoint databases on the SQL instance?

Comment: yes there are also non-sharepoint databases. why is that inportant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is something have to do with permissions. Check if the account running the configuration wizard have:

- The domain user account permissions.
- Must be a member of the local administrators group on each server in the SharePoint farm.
- Must must have access to the SharePoint databases.
- If you use any Windows PowerShell operations that affect a database, the setup user administrator account must be a member of the db_owner role.
- Must be assigned to the securityadmin and dbcreator SQL Server security roles during setup and configuration.
- If the account that you use to run the configuration wizards does not have the **appropriate special SQL Server role membership** or access as **db_owner** on the databases, **the configuration wizards will not run correctly.**

You can read more on [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

Comment: Thanks, I give the farm account execture permissions and now it is working. thanks